# Minimum chunk size for browsers to render

Tags: http, browser, chunked-encoding

I have been working on chunked transfer encoding for few weeks and created a framework to achieve [BigPipe](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919/). It is collecting contents from different applications and streams into a single page. It really optimizes the progressive rendering and overall loading time.

But my problem starts when first flush size is less than 1 kb. Sometimes I can observe that browsers are not rendering when first chunk size is less than a kb. What is the most ideal chunk size to flush? Or size is only important for first flushes which includes headers? Or is it possible to send smaller chunk but force it to render?